# Watson conversation context

Tags: watson-conversation, watson-dialog

I am currently working with the watson chatbot conversation application. i ran into a situation where i have to refresh a context, just at a certain stage depending on the user input, but i haven't been able to achieve this.

```
I tried setting the context = {}, if the user input isn't in the Array, but it seems to check the context at every stage of the Application. 

if(context.city !== array[i]['city']){
        context = {};
 }

what i am asking the user is to input a list of cities, which is in an Array. If the user inputs a location that isn't in the Array first, it let's the user know that it isn't in the Array. If the user inputs a city that is not in the Array after inputing a city that is already in the array, it is returning the last context. 

for example,

City = Boston.
You just input Boston, price is 20.
Then if i do City = Atlanta(Bearing in mind Atlanta is not in the Array)
it does city is Atlanta, price is 20. 

Any idea how to fix this, on any steps i can follow to stop this from happening?
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
  if (context.city !== array[i]['city']){
    if(inputBox.value ===  context.city)
    {
    context = latestResponse.context;
    context.rate = rate;
    context.currency = currency;
    }
    else
    {
      context.city = "";
      context.rate = "";
      context.currency = "";
    }
  }
}
```

For someone else that might be going through the same problem now or in the future,

This was what solved it for me. The information needed was in an Array, so i looped over it, and checked if the context.city != array.

Answer (score 0):

You can set context.city to empty string or null in your app or in advanced editor
[image]
 and then in your app fix logic based on that

Comment: Thank you, i actually figured out a way to do it about 10 minutes after posting this. Thank you.